# Unit testig on multisite

Tags: 8, entities, database, multi-sites, testing

I am trying to simulate a multi-site environment in an integration test with phpunit. I know how to init a new database connection with `Database::addConnectionInfo` but how can I cleanly switch the database used by the current environment?

`Database::setActiveConnection` will only work for SQL queries but I would like to use the entity_type.manager service and the only way I found is to replace the database service in the container and call `KernelTest::setUp`. Switching back an forth between the databases is still pretty buggy and complex.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

"Unit testing" and "multi-site" are in direct conflict with each other. Multi-site is definitely an integration/functional testing concern.

What you *can* do in a unit test to help guarantee that things are working correctly for a multi-site setup is to unit test *only* the logic that is computing different results for each site in the multi-site setup. Use a `@dataProvider` to test the input for different sites in a multi-site setup.

The result of that logic [should vary by the `url.site` cache context](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts). You can assert the presence of that cache context in the `X-Drupal-Cache-Contexts` response header in your integration/functional test.

IOW:
- unit test for testing various inputs, with a `@dataProvider`
- functional test that asserts the presence of `url.site` cache context

Together, they guarantee things work correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer! So there is no stable way to execute code in two different drupal instances (e.g. to use the entity_type.manager to create nodes) right? I would like to write integration tests for a node replication via rest endpoints (relaxed module) and would have an easier game by jumping between instances instead of using curl with the rest endpoints for every task.